# Various forms of the Confluent Heun Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

The Confluent Heun equation is expressed in various forms. It's non-symmetrical canonical form is:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+(\beta+\frac{\gamma}{x}+\frac{\delta}{x-1})\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{\alpha\beta x-q}{x(x-1)} y =0
\end{equation}

with a particular transformation it is possible to change it to a Schrodinger-like equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+(A+\frac{B}{x}+\frac{C}{x-1}+\frac{D}{x^{2}}+\frac{E}{(x-1)^{2}})y=0
\end{equation}

What is the transformation in order to go from one form to another? and how are $A, B, C, D$ and $E$ related to $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ and $q$?

Comment: To eliminate the first derivative you may try an ansatz $y(x)=\alpha(x)z(x)$. Choose $\alpha(x)$ so that the terms containing the first derivative vanishs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y(x)$ is a solution of the first equation, let
$$  z \left( x \right) =y \left( x \right) {{\rm e}^{\beta\,x/2}}{x}^{
\gamma/2} \left( x-1 \right) ^{\delta/2}$$

Then if I'm not mistaken, $z$ satisfies the second differential equation with

$$ A = -\dfrac{\beta^2}{4},\ B = \dfrac{2q + (\delta-\beta)\gamma}{2},\
C = \dfrac{2\alpha\beta - (\beta+\gamma)\delta - 2 q}{2},\
D = \dfrac{(2-\gamma)\gamma}{4},\ E = \dfrac{(2-\delta)\delta}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.